# Github API - How to know if an issue was closed by a fork pull request?

Tags: github, github-api

How can I know given an closed issue, if it was closed through a pull request, specifically through a fork pull request, and how can I get the Id of the fork?

I've been reading in the issues/pull request/events API docs but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible using [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) using [`timelineItems`](https://developer.github.com/v4/union/issuetimelineitems/) and filtering on event with state `CLOSED_EVENT`

```graphql
{
  repository(name: "material-ui", owner: "mui-org") {
    issue(number: 19641) {
      timelineItems(itemTypes: CLOSED_EVENT, last: 1) {
        nodes {
          ... on ClosedEvent {
            createdAt
            closer {
              ...on PullRequest {
                baseRefName
                baseRepository {
                  nameWithOwner
                }
                headRefName
                headRepository {
                  nameWithOwner
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20repository%28name%3A%20%22material-ui%22%2C%20owner%3A%20%22mui-org%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20issue%28number%3A%2019641%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20timelineItems%28itemTypes%3A%20CLOSED_EVENT%2C%20last%3A%201%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20ClosedEvent%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20createdAt%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20closer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...on%20PullRequest%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20baseRefName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20baseRepository%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nameWithOwner%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20headRefName%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20headRepository%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nameWithOwner%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

The `closer` field contains the source of the closing :

- [via pull request](https://github.blog/2013-05-14-closing-issues-via-pull-requests/): `PullRequest`
- [via commit messages](https://github.blog/2013-01-22-closing-issues-via-commit-messages/): `Commit`
- or via the closed button: `null`

The following requests are example for the 3 types of closing

### Closing via pull request

[This pull request](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/21107) closed [this issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/19641)

```graphql
{
  repository(name: "material-ui", owner: "mui-org") {
    issue(number: 19641) {
      timelineItems(itemTypes: CLOSED_EVENT, last: 1) {
        nodes {
          ... on ClosedEvent {
            createdAt
            closer {
              __typename
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "issue": {
        "timelineItems": {
          "nodes": [
            {
              "createdAt": "2020-05-20T09:06:11Z",
              "closer": {
                "__typename": "PullRequest"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Closing via commit message

[This commit](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/commit/ac420247b365191e1abe62cd8c6ea5847eb417b6) closed [this issue](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/issues/1536)

```graphql
{
  repository(name: "rubinius", owner: "rubinius") {
    issue(number: 1536) {
      timelineItems(itemTypes: CLOSED_EVENT, last: 1) {
        nodes {
          ... on ClosedEvent {
            createdAt
            closer {
              __typename
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "issue": {
        "timelineItems": {
          "nodes": [
            {
              "createdAt": "2012-01-30T22:33:11Z",
              "closer": {
                "__typename": "Commit"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Closing via button

[This issue](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/issues/3830) was closed via the close button :

```graphql
{
  repository(name: "rubinius", owner: "rubinius") {
    issue(number: 3830) {
      timelineItems(itemTypes: CLOSED_EVENT, last: 1) {
        nodes {
          ... on ClosedEvent {
            createdAt
            closer {
              __typename
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "issue": {
        "timelineItems": {
          "nodes": [
            {
              "createdAt": "2020-02-02T22:31:05Z",
              "closer": null
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Amdguez I don't think so, I've tried using the events api for a specific pull request using API v3, but it only gives the commitId/commitUrl for the "commit" closing type. [via button](https://api.github.com/repos/rubinius/rubinius/issues/3830/events) and [via pull request](https://api.github.com/repos/mui-org/material-ui/issues/19641/events) returns null values for commitId/commitUrl but nothing can be used to detect if it was closed by button or Pull request.